# How do I edit the properties of controls made using QTCreator in Slot declaration?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I made a form using QTCreator. Then I change some of its properties in class constructor  like

```
ui->cancelButton->hide();
```

It work. Now I declare a custom slot in header file & tried to use controls' properties in Slot implementation in class file (i.e .cpp) like

```
oldName = lineEDit->text();
```

but I get error msg

```
error: 'LineEdit' was not declared in this scope
```

then I tried like

```
oldName = ui->nameLine->text();
```

but it gives same error. How do I use controls' properties in Slots declaration or other functions when I made UI using Designer ??

**EDIT: SLOT SOURCE**

```
void addressbook::addContact()
 {
     oldName    = ui->nameLine->text();  //nameLine->text();
     oldAddress = ui->addressText->toPlainText(); //addressText->toPlainText();

     nameLine->clear();
     addressText->clear();

     updateInterface(AddingMode);
 }
```

Comment: Is ui a member of the class? What's the object name defined in designer? You can also check the ui_foo.h file generated by uic for the names of the members.

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld: good question! I have infect no idea,as I see this usage in video tutorial.The occurrence of ui in code is at constructor implementation like 'addressbook::addressbook(QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent),ui(new Ui::addressbook)'

Comment: I am not able to find ui_foo.h in project files anywhere though its included in headers files list of cpp file created by QTCreator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you creating class Test it would produce 4 files:

```
    1) test.h - your class header 
    2) test.cpp - your implementation
    3) test.ui - form descriptor
    4) ui_test.h - file generated from form descriptor,
 containing cpp code to create it.
```

test_ui.h has a class declaration inside, with the set of members with types and names of objects you put on form. `Ui::TestClass`

your main class will have it as private member

```
private:
    Ui::TestClass ui;
```

so if you want to adress form elements do it as ui->ObjectNameFromForm

And - have a look onto your ui_***.h classes, it is normal cpp code, and after researching them you may understand much more clear how forms works.

Comment: thank you very much. But there is no ui_2.h class in my projects file. There is only one .h file that is test.h

Comment: that files included automatically with setting UI+=test.ui. Look for them around your source files, project won't compile without them generated. They may be in subdir called "Generated files" or something similar.

Comment: one more thing is by ObjectNameFromForm if ur are referring the names that I given to controls on form using ObjectName property then I am using those. & those are automatically shown by ide once I type ui->.

Comment: haven't you forgot to add ObjectNameFromForm:: prefix to your function body?

Comment: I have already seen all places under project,infect keep all folders are always open.There is one .pro file & three folders named, Headers; Sources;Forms; No other file OR folder.

Comment: no, I did not use ObjectNameFromForm prefix at any place. I am thinking u r referring it for controls' names. As I see a tutorial video & they use syntax like ui->...here all control names on form are highlighted. Can u kindly write one complete example statement here

Comment: hmmm... that files should be in the sources folder, at least on windows they are there.

Comment: provide the code for function where you calling to `oldName = ui->nameLine->text();` , i suggest you just forgot to define its class in body. 
for `class c{ void f();};` function body should be `void c::f(){}; `

Comment: change      `nameLine->clear();
     addressText->clear();` to `ui->nameLine->clear();
     ui->addressText->clear();`
they are members of ui, aren't them

Comment: oh yes, I use ui in first statements but forget about these two. Thanks a Thousands Times Raiv :)

Comment: OK, one thing I noticed that ui_test.h is included in headers files of cpp file by QTCreator though the file is not there visible.